# Handling "Don't Save" flow for Save Prompt in Word Document

Tags: c#, ms-word

We are working with Word document in C# and performing various operations through code. We are facing problems when user selects "Don't Save" when prompted for Saving the unsaved changes prior to exiting the word document. As our data is getting changes when we change the document, these changes need to be reverted back if user chooses not to save them.

I have come across various solutions but all of them have "Before Close" events of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` dll and none of them are getting fired once the Save Prompt appears.

Please suggest any solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you mistake is that you work with the original document,
you should rather work with a copy of the document and overwrite the original document if the user wants to save his changes.

Comment: We do want to prompt warning message to user when he chooses "Don't Save".Any way to Trap that event? once the Save Prompt is closed and user has made a choice?

Answer (score 0):

If the user chooses "Don't Save", then there should be no changes to revert, since the user is explicitly asking to discard them.

You should be working on a copy of the document, so that the originally opened document stays as it is before anything is saved. You can then reference that original, unchanged copy again the next time the document is opened.

Comment: We do want to prompt warning message to user when he chooses "Don't Save".Any way to Trap that event? once the Save Prompt is closed and user has made a choice?